# PYTHON - how to return the window size of a cv2.imshow window?

Tags: python, opencv

since i used `cv2.namedWindow('Frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` I was able to resize my window while running but I also want to print the new window size. Anyone who could help?

Update:
This is not the full code but it's something like this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('Frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    print(frame.shape) #prints image dimension
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It kept printing (480, 640, 3) even after I resized the window

Comment: image size is the window size. so print the image size you're going to print.

Comment: i tried that but the image size stayed the same. Don't know why :(

Comment: could you please upload the full code?

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa pls see my updated post :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following command.

```
cv2.getWindowImageRect('Frame')
```

This will return a tuple of `(x, y, w, h)` with the current information of the image that is showing in the window named `'Frame'`.

Note: This will return the details of the **image**, but **not** the information of the window that the image is in.

Edit Note: This function appears after `opencv` `3.4.1` release.